# Python Mapper on Amazon EMR

Tags: python, amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, amazon-emr

I'm trying to run a Python script as a mapper on Amazon EMR.

The initial portion of my script resembles:

```
import sys
import decimal

def some_function(sensor_record):
    return 1
```

That results in the following error output:

```
[...]/mapper_script.py: line 1: import: command not found
[...]/mapper_script.py: line 2: import: command not found
[...]/mapper_script.py: line 5: syntax error near unexpected token `('
[...]/mapper_script.py: line 5: `def some_function(sensor_record):'
```

Any thoughts on this? I've used EMR successfully before but not with Python. 
I get the same result running the job through the web interface and using the
boto library.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You just need to add

```
   #!/usr/bin/env python
```

at the beginning of the script to ensure that EMR picks the right language.